# Odoo paper format delete

Tags: odoo

I'm running Odoo 8.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. All is working very well, but I can't see any way to delete a Paper Format once created. There's no option to delete from the "More" button. Am I missing something here?

How do I delete a Paper Format?

Comment: are you talking about report paper format?

Answer (score 7):

Hear the paper formate configuration is available if and only if you have successfully install the report module in our system.

first need to install the report module in Odoo 8.0

then after you should follow the below steps to do the delete the paper formate in our system

[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope this should helpful for you :)

Comment: perfect answer, at that ways delete it, thx for the information .

Answer (score 2):

You can also delete the paper format from the xml by :

```
<delete id="your_xml_id" model="report.paperformat"/>
```

It will delete the paper format, as in above answer it will regenerate will server restarts.